Help with Posterior Distribution for a Poisson-Gaussian Process Model
I'm working on a regression model where variable Y is regressed on x, expressed as
$$y_i | f(x_i) \sim \text{Poisson}(\exp(f(x_i)))$$
for i.i.d observations (i = 1, ..., n). Here, (f) is modeled as a Gaussian process (GP) across an interval J ⊆ R. This function (f) is characterized by a mean function (\mu(x)) and a kernel function (K(x, x')), leading to the formulation
$$f(x) \sim N_p(\mu(x), K(x, x)).$$
I'm aiming to infer the posterior (f|y, x), specifically focusing on sampling from the posterior for selected points (x^*) within (J) to effectively represent (f). Could you help derive the posterior of (f(x)) up to a normalizing constant using Bayes' formula? This should consider the Poisson and multivariate normal distributions' densities and any simplifications due to conditional independencies. I share below my current solution, in case someone can check if it makes sense, or just provide a better derivation.
Given the model:
$$
y_i | f, x_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\exp(f(x_i))) \quad \text{for } i = 1, \ldots, n,
$$
and the Gaussian Process prior for (f):
$$
f \sim \text{GP}(\mu, K),
$$
the likelihood of observing the data (y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)) given the function (f) and inputs (x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)) is:
$$
p(y | f, x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \exp(-\exp(f(x_i))) \frac{\exp(f(x_i))^{y_i}}{y_i!}.
$$
The Gaussian Process prior is given by:
$$
p(f | x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2} |K|^{1/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (f - \mu)^T K^{-1} (f - \mu)\right).
$$
By Bayes’ theorem, the posterior is proportional to the product of the likelihood and the prior:
$$
p(f | x, y) \propto p(y | f, x) p(f | x).
$$
Thus, we have:
$$
p(f | x, y) \propto \prod_{i=1}^n \exp(-\exp(f(x_i))) \frac{\exp(f(x_i))^{y_i}}{y_i!} \cdot \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2} |K|^{1/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (f - \mu)^T K^{-1} (f - \mu)\right).
$$
Simplifying, and noting that the factorials in the likelihood do not depend on (f), we can write:
$$
p(f | x, y) \propto \exp \left(- \sum_{i=1}^n \exp(f(x_i)) + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i f(x_i) - \frac{1}{2} (f - \mu)^T K^{-1} (f - \mu)\right).
$$
This expression can be used for inferential purposes, focusing on Bayesian updating of our beliefs about (f) based on observed data (y) and inputs (x).

The $y_i$'s are not iid.
